# Heterogenous Database Replication

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, replication, transactional-replication

How can we establish a real time synchronization from SQL server to PostgreSQL Database? We have tried to automate the jobs in BI but that does not serve the purpose as we need real time data from source database. Do I need to use third party tools or would SQL Server Management Studio be sufficient to achieve this?

Comment: You could try https://debezium.io/